# Laravel - Need to access a global variable set in BaseController from within a model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, model, global

I am creating a change logging system for replicating changes made to a table.  This function essentially uses the beforeUpdate() hook, and allows me to make a copy of the old data in the ChangeLog for that table.  I also want to tag it with some specific information such as the IP address making the request, and the user ID that made the request.

The user id is stored in a global variable inside of the BaseController class, which is accessible to any controller using $this->userId, however, I do not want to have to explicitly pass in that user id to every model call, so I would like to be able to access the $this->userId from with my various models, but laravel models apparently don't let you talk to the controller that way by just referencing $this->userId.

Can anyone give me an idea how to go about this?  I've been digging for hours and can't find anything that does what I need?

Thanks so much,
Wade

Comment: I am using Laravel 4

Comment: if you don't want to pass the dependency you could store the ID in the session and get it wherever you want

Comment: This looks like a good suggestion, then it would available in the entire session without having to specify a particular model.  I would give this a ^ if I could, but thank you!

Comment: i've posted an answer adding another alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically if you don't want to pass the dependency you have two ways:

1 - Use session: you could store the ID in the session and get it wherever you want

2 - Create a service provider or a class to store the data you want and retrieve it later using the app Registry:

To do that you can create a class to store your data, then bind the instance on the service container:

```
$service = new ServiceClass( $id );  //this will contain the data you need: i.e the ID

$app->instance('your_key', $service);  //store the instante in the IoC Container
```

Now you can get back the instance wherever you want with:

```
$service = $app->make('your_key');
```

and you could also create a Facade to access it

As a final note: code written in this way smells like 'bad global stuff' so you should consider passing the dependecy along to your models as long as you can

Comment: Using the session is in my opinion the best approach because that's exactly what it's supposed to be used for and makes much more sense than making it a property of the base controller.  With that said, there is an easier approach to using the service container.  It's possible to simply bind a value to it with no need for an additional class.  `App::bind('userid', function() { return 'someUserId' });`.

Comment: @user3158900 : what you're saying is true, a class would be more appropriate to store more complex data

Comment: This is kind of an edge case.  I typically do pass along what I need thru the controller to a model, but I'm doing a "full record" based change long using beforeChange() hook, I want to get that user id globally without having to pass it in.  The session worked perfectly for my needs in this case, but I really like the other ideas you guys have posted.  I may experiment with the app registry idea too. I wasn't aware of that feature.

I'm basically creating a copy of the original record before it is overwritten with any changes, plus adding in a few bits of info identifying who made the change.

Answer (score 1):

By creating scope you can get the userID value in your model.
For example, in the article model if I want to check if the author of the article is the current user or not I can make my own scope as:

```
public function scopeUserid($query,$id){
    $query->where('user_id',$id);
}
```

In the controller you can pass the userID by

```
$allArticlesFromCurrentAuthor = Article::userid($this->userId)->get();
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: You forgot the `return` statement. :) `return $query->where('user_id',$id);`

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This solution is great, but it looks like I would need to pass the userId into EACH model that I need to use it in, correct?

Comment: Thanks for the correction Thomas but it works even without return statement. And yes Wade we have to pass userId as an argument to the every model.